# How to capture screenshot in case of error in a called feature?

Tags: karate, intuit-partner-platform

I am trying to capture a screenshot after any step failure in a called feature. I tried using

```
configure afterScenario = function(){ if (karate.info.errorMessage) driver.screenshot() }
```

for that but realized that the hooks don't work for the called feature files. Is there any other way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Can you first upgrade to 1.0.1 and confirm, Karate should automatically take a screenshot and add it to the report on an error.

Else please go through this thread for ideas: https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/1465

It may require you to dig into Karate internals and contribute code, so if you are not prepared to do that - you can opt for other alternative solutions.